# Webview in Cocoa Application not proceed for authentication dialog?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, authentication, webview, webkit

I am trying to make a request through Webview (webkit) within cocoa application to a secured website. After the webframe launched, an authentication dialog pops up in the Webview let user to type username and password. However, after user click login button, authenticate dialog disappeared, but no request is generated and send to the server, thus none of the webview delegate method can catch this event. The webview hang with no content in it in the end.

I tried to use the delegate method didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge and hard code my credential in this method to challenge the authentication dialog, the website let me pass through without the authentication dialog pop up. However, I need to let user to type in credential after authentication dialog pop up.

Any one has idea on how to implement a Webview that can handle authentication dialog login after user input credential? Or is this a Webkit bug that does not handle this workflow?

BTW, if I make the same request in Safari, I can see dialog popup, I entered credential, the browser proceed and server let me logged in.

Thank you.